# SSL connection error on connecting to MySQL server in Rust

Tags: mysql, rest, ssl, rust

I am learning Rust. I setup a Rust API open source application on 64bit Windows 10, i.e. [REST API with Rust using Actix-Web 2.0](https://github.com/dansoy/rust-api). I am trying to get it to connect to MySQL 8.0 running locally on this very machine. I setup a `.env` file with proper credentials for MySQL database on this Windows machine running Wampserver MySql. When I try to run it using `cargo run`, I get the following error and some stack trace:

`panicked at 'Failed to create db pool.: Error(Some("SSL connection error: unknown error number"))', src\db.rs:23:28`

Some solutions suggest that the client which is trying to connect to DB is old and doesn't support the latest protocols like TLS 1.2 etc. But I don't think that is the issue. I didn't find any mention of this error with Rust. Am I missing something?

- Can I connect to MySQL without SSL?
- Do I need to setup certificates at client and server end?
- Do I need to setup OpenSSL?

Here is the complete code of file `db.rs` whose line 23 fails when it runs after a successful compilation.

```rust
use diesel::mysql::MysqlConnection;
use diesel::r2d2::{ConnectionManager, Pool, PooledConnection};
use lazy_static::lazy_static;
use crate::errors::ApiError;

type MysqlPool = Pool<ConnectionManager<MysqlConnection>>;
pub type DbConnection = PooledConnection<ConnectionManager<MysqlConnection>>;

embed_migrations!();

lazy_static!{
    static ref POOL: MysqlPool = {
        let conn = std::env::var("DB_CONNECTION").expect("DB_CONNECTION must be set");
        let host = std::env::var("DB_HOST").expect("DB_HOST must be set");
        let port = std::env::var("DB_PORT").expect("DB_PORT must be set");
        let dbname = std::env::var("DB_DATABASE").expect("DB_DATABASE must be set");
        let username = std::env::var("DB_USERNAME").expect("DB_USERNAME must be set");
        let password = std::env::var("DB_PASSWORD").expect("DB_PASSWORD must be set");
        
        let database_url = format!("{}://{}:{}@{}:{}/{}", conn, username, password, host, port, dbname);

        let manager = ConnectionManager::<MysqlConnection>::new(database_url);
        Pool::new(manager).expect("Failed to create db pool.")
    };
}

pub fn init() {
    info!("Initializing Database...");
    lazy_static::initialize(&POOL);
    let conn = connection().expect("Failed to get db connection.");
    embedded_migrations::run(&conn).unwrap();
}

pub fn connection() -> Result<DbConnection, ApiError> {
    POOL.get()
        .map_err(|e| ApiError::new(500, format!("Failed getting db connection: {}", e)))
}
```

Comment: Since this is a local app connecting to a local MySql instance ... you *SHOULD* be able to connect without SSL (e.g. on port 3306).  You just need the right Rust library: https://docs.rs/mysql/latest/mysql/

Comment: Here is the solution to making `diesel` talk to MySQL without SSL. Use the below connectstring:  

`let database_url = format!("{}://{}:{}@{}:{}/{}?ssl_mode=DISABLED", conn, username, password, host, port, dbname);`    

Although the above code is still not working. On debugging, it seems there is some issue in `lazy_static`.